# Plotting data with meshgrid

Tags: matlab, plot

When you use meshgrid to plot data (using meshgrid itself not one of the other plotting functions), how do you change the color to grayscale or black and white? Also, how do you get rid of the "meshy" look of the image?

Answer (score 1):

To change the colour to greyscale you can use:

```
colormap(gray);
```

As for the 'meshy' look, I'm not 100% sure what you mean; but I'm assuming whatever you've created is looking pixelated? If so, decrease your mesh spacing:

From

```
x = meshgrid(-25:25);
```

To

```
x = meshgrid(-25:0.5:25);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works for meshgrid, but if you use [surf](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/surf.html), you can specify

```
shading interp
```

to get rid of the 'meshy' look.

Comment: or shading flat if you don't want to interpolate.  If you want the grid back, it's shading faceted or some such